# After setting up local dev environment with database-migration plugin, how to then update test servers

Tags: grails, database-migration, liquibase

Following the documentation I was able to get the database-migration plugin working on an existing project which already has quite a few tables and is running in production.  I went through the following process locally:

```
Pulled down latest production database
Source production database to local dev
grails dbm-generate-changelog changelog.groovy
grails dbm-changelog-sync
grails dbm-gorm-diff 2012-06-25-latest.groovy --add
grails dbm-update
```

I understand why I had to do each of those locally to get to a point of applying future change sets.  However, now I want to run my 2012-06-25-latest.groovy on one of my test servers.  It already has the latest database based on our production database.

I tried just running dbm-update but without the sync it failed creating tables that already exist.  So I ran dbm-changelog-sync but then when running dbm-update it didn't actually apply the latest file.

I know that I can add a context (tag) to the change sets and specify that context when running dbm-update but I want to know if this is the only way to go about this or if my workflow needs to be modified; what is the best way to go about applying the changelog to the test server?

Comment: After doing changlog-sync on test env - what happened when you try to run dbm-update ? Also I assume that you are doing it like 'grails test dbm-update' - Specifying the environment in the command

Comment: I said the following in my question "So I ran dbm-changelog-sync but then when running dbm-update it didn't actually apply the latest file.".  And yes, I am specifying the environment.

Comment: When you do dbm-changelog-sync it registers all the current changesets as being applied, so if you are expecting any of existing changesets in your base chabgelog.groovy to execyte- they won't apply when your do dbm-update. However if you add new changesets and then do dbm-update - they should execute fine.

And this being a test environment - why do you worry about changelog sync, you can just do dbm-drop-all and then dbm-update and thereafter every thing should be fine

Comment: I understand that and thanks. I don't want my base changelog.groovy to execute.  I want my 2012-06-25-latest.groovy to execute.

Comment: Okey great -Then, I think there's no alternative. on a fresh db you have to either drop and recreate or sync changelogs, but once you sync there's probably no way to run few of them. Let us know if you find some solution

Comment: However if your 2012-06-25-latest.groovy has not been synced to test db, changesets in that file should execute fine, given that the file is included properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing is deleting all the rows in the DATABASECHANGELOG table where the FILENAME = '2012-06-25-latest.groovy'.  I then ran dbm-status and it told me I had 256 changes waiting.  I then ran dbm-update and all is well.

I'm not sure this is how it was supposed to be done, but it seems to have worked.

UPDATE: In addition to this I could probably run the entire migration on an empty database, and then do a mysqldump of the production database with INSERT statements only.

Comment: yeah so you had synced changes in 2012-06-25-latest.groovy as well.. if dint sync changes in that file, just dbm-update would have gone fine.

Comment: Dude, I get that.  The problem is that that file already existed from doing this process locally.  So when I ran the sync, of course it sync'd that file.  You're not really telling me anything I don't already know. :o)

Comment: Okey - great I was just trying to help - Just lil surprized that when you already knew all this stuff - what was the question about.

Comment: I understand you're trying to help.  The question was how is the process supposed to work. The docs aren't clear on what happens when you move the process to a server.